# Ajax with jQuery works in Firefox and gets 404 error in Chrome

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome

I have this ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: 'json',
    error: function(result) {
        alert('Error: ' + result.status);
    },
    type: 'GET',
    data: "",
    success: function(data) {
        //do some stuff
    },
    url: 'info/' + hash + '.json'
});
```

And while in Firefox this works great, in Chrome I get a 404 error, how can I fix it to work in Chrome too?

Comment: try specifying the url at the top

Comment: also if you are not sending the data just dont specify it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use a full url-

```
url: 'http://yoursite.com/YourDirectorys/info/' + hash + '.json
```

or a none relative url-

```
url: '/YourDirectorys/info/' + hash + '.json
```